# Finding base packages with APT?

Tags: search, packages, apt, apt-cache

This has been bugging me for a while now.  If I want to install the xfce desktop environment for example, I can use `apt-cache search xfce` - but this gives me 500 results, when all im looking for is the base package, not secondary packages for the desktop itself.  How would I effectively find the base package for things?

Answer (score 2):

Try using for `apt-cache search ^xfce | less`.

This way you only search for the packages that *begins* with xfce. (With `less`, you can go trough them a page at a time).